# Can't open recently created cloud function to edit/update, but functions still trigger successfully

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

We recently pushed a set of our functions into a new project and after deploying we noticed that we cannot access any of the functions through the GCP interface. Whenever we select a function, we get a **"Failed to Load."** error and then the text:

> There was an error while loading
>   /functions/details/us-central1/**[function name]**?project=**[project-id]**.
>   Please try again.

These functions are still running successfully upon triggering, but we can't access them to make any changes.

Any suggestions? Should we delete and redeploy?

**We are using the in-line editor, & Python 3.7.**

**EDIT:** Additional Details

We have also seen issues when trying to deploy scheduled queries, any click to create sends us right back to the BQ UI. A few of our BQ tables won't load into table preview, but can still be queried.

**EDIT:** Added photo
[image: Cloud Function Failed to Load]

Comment: Do your functions contain multiple files, or are they all in a single file?

Comment: Single file for the function. I'm also noticing other errors in the project as a whole, with a few BQ tables not opening and scheduled query APIs throwing errors. I'm wondering if the project had an issue upon set up (we just created this project recently).

Answer (score 0):

This can be a trantient issue.

While the Cloud functions are not editable on the console the work around is is tu use the Cloud Functions API to retrive the code, then you can edit the code on your local host and finally deploy it again with the corrections with the gcloud command.

for this the steps are:

1. Run teh following command on CloudShell

`curl -X POST  -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/locations/<LOCATION>/functions/<FUNCTION_ID>:generateDownloadUrl`

2. This will generate a URL where you can download your code on a zipfile. Download it
3. Uncompress the zipfile and update your code as intended
4. Update your file as intended
5. on cloud shell move to an empty folder
6. Upload the files to Cloud Shell (for this you can go to Options-> Upload File)
7. use the command to deploy the cloud function:
   `gcloud functions deploy`

Comment: This will likely work to access code and make changes, but it won't help our team utilize anything in the UI when we need to make quick changes. I'm seeing issues in other areas of GCP, is it possible when the project got created there was a larger problem that would lead to cross-project load issues?

Comment: as of this last comment it seems to be a project specific issue, for this I would recommend you to create a case with [GCP Support](https://console.cloud.google.com/support/createcase)

Comment: Our org doesn't have role based support. Are there other resolution opportunities for getting support?